# Add a text field on button click to second main activity

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I need to add text field depends on the number the user added in the number text field to the second main activity. I already have a button that open `onClick` a new MainActivity but I need also to add text fields in the second MainActivity depends the number added.

I tried adding text fields on `actionListeners` but still not working.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button submit_textfield;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        submit_textfield = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_textfield);
        submit_textfield.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity2();


            }
        });}

    public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

The results must be: the user enters 5 and click submit the page redirect and creates 5 text fields. Thank You.

Comment: You must pass the value as an extra to the second activity through the intent in openActivity2(). Use intent.putExtra("name", "value") and pass the Integer value. Then, in the second activity's onCreate method, you can read the value by calling getIntent().getIntExtra("name") and then you create your text views.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieving this you have to add a dynamic linear layout in which you will add textviews on run time nad firstly you have to pass that number into the intent by putExtra method.

```
public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("number",submit_textfield.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);    
    }
```

Now you just have to get this value in the next activity and start a for loop for this value and add runtime textviews in the linear layout.

```
int number =0;
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
number = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("number"));
}
LinearLayout ll= findViewById(R.id.ll_layout);
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    final TextView tv_text= new TextView(this);
    tv_text.setText("Value " + i);
    ll.addView(tv_text);
}
```

if you want to set these textviews in vertical orientation then you just have to add the params to the linear layout as mentioned below:

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Welcome dear let e know if you need any other help.

Comment: Well noted, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> the user enters 5 and click submit the page redirect and creates 5
>   textfields

For this, you need to pass the `text` value into another class by using `Intent`.
Then you can receive the value by using `getIntExtra` in `Main2Activity`.

```
 public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("num",submit_textfield.getText());
        startActivity(intent);    
    }
```

After get the `num` value, you can create the `TextView` dynamically based on the number.

**Main2Activity**

```
int num = getIntent().getIntExtra("num",0);
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
    rowTextView.setText("Value " + i);
    myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
}
```

**Output**

[image]